# Why wasn't this question, closed as "Belongs on SuperUser", migrated to SU?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, migration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185275/why-windows-right-click-new-is-so-slow-closed) was closed [a few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1185275/list), but not automatically migrated. That's a shame; it's a good question (for SU). What happened?

Comment: Not sure, but someone posted the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185275/why-windows-right-click-new-is-so-slow/1185282#1185282

Comment: it looks as though the post in question has recently been reopened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a question to be automatically migrated upon close, 3 of the 5 close votes must be for the migration.

The question being discussed only had 2 "belongs on superuser.com" close votes - here's the breakdown with vote cast time:

```
subjective and argumentative    2009-07-26 18:58:52.980
belongs on superuser.com        2009-07-26 19:00:06.753
not programming related         2009-07-26 19:00:32.837
not programming related         2009-07-26 19:00:49.030
belongs on superuser.com        2009-07-26 19:02:20.213
```

Since there was no clear winner, the last close vote cast is the one used in the close reason.  Perhaps a better scheme would be to choose the highest rep user's reason in ties?

Regardless, this migration threshold is in place to ensure that the community has enough consensus before displacing a question and all its answers.

Comment: One rather large annoyance in the way the migration system works is that you have to *reopen* then *re-close* a question if its already closed in order to move it. I think that allowing voting to move regardless of the open/closed status is desirable, perhaps going so far as to completely separate the closing and migration votes.

Comment: I agree - it used to be that way for moderators, when there was only one possible target for migration (SO -> SF and vice versa).  I just haven't updated the moderator script to fetch possible migration targets.  I'll look into it, as I'm tweaking some of the close script's usability.

Answer (score 1):

From the [July14th blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/), Jeff writes:

> This is still a vote-based process,
> unless a moderator intervenes. If the
> post reaches the close vote threshold
> (currently requires 5 close votes,
> with a majority of the belongs-on
> type), then it is migrated to the
> other website.

As you know, there has been a good amount of talk about moving questions by low rep users to SuperUser, specifically that the site is currently in beta, and even though it is publicly available (if you know who/how to ask) it might not be obvious to the user where his/her question has gone.

With this in mind perhaps a moderator intervened, or perhaps there was a decision to not auto migrate to SuperUser for the time being.

Apologies for not providing a *real* answer, but adding this color via comment would have been burdensome.