# Closed "Belongs on" question not migrated?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why wasn’t this question, closed as “Belongs on SuperUser”, migrated to SU?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9857/why-wasnt-this-question-closed-as-belongs-on-superuser-migrated-to-su)

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786571/what-is-the-difference-between-fedora-unix-and-fedora-linux). It was closed as "Belongs on superuser.com," but not migrated. I was hence able to edit it to remove the `[belongs-on-*]` tags which had been applied.

Under what conditions would a question which is closed as belonging to a sister site not get migrated?

Comment: Yah, the link just links to superuser.  Odd...

Comment: AFAIK, that happens when the "belongs on" option gets the most votes of any option, but not a *majority* of the votes. 

This has been asked here before, looking for it now...

Comment: ah right - so it wasn't a majority. Makes sense.

Comment: @Shog9: Did you find the dupe? (I couldn't when I tried; but if this is a dupe I'd like to get it closed as such.)

Comment: I couldn't find anything. Donno what I was thinking of, but either it didn't happen, or the title was something way off what I remember.

Comment: Here's another I just ran across: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985413/creating-a-very-small-linux-closed. I was going to ask this myself until this question popped up in the auto-search.

Comment: And hey, look what else showed up in the auto-search: Shog9's duplicate, asked by Shog9 himself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9857/why-wasnt-this-question-closed-as-belongs-on-superuser-migrated-to-su.

Comment: @mmyers: Thanks for the link; voted to close as dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice the close reason states "closed" rather than "migrated" - which might have some bearing on the problem.

[Marc's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31000/after-adding-migrate-flag-auto-migration-after-10-such-flags/31006#31006) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31000/after-adding-migrate-flag-auto-migration-after-10-such-flags) sheds some light:

> the consensus site of any "migrate" votes is chosen as the target; if there is no consensus, it is simply closed without migrate

Comment: With the edit, you get the accept. (Need to get my percentage up anyway. :) )

Answer (score 0):

And we're back to the problem that many of us just don't know what's considered appropriate on other sites.  I'm primarily a SO guy, and I have to decide, given an off-topic question, whether it would belong on SF, SU, or neither.  I'd be happier about it if somebody from one of those communities needed to be involved on a migration.

Comment: In your scenario, vote to close as not-programming-related. Always valid in that case!

Comment: @user0x36E0:  Sure, that's what I do.  Which means that I may be shutting down a question that would do just fine on SF or SU, since I'm less familiar with those sites.  I don't think there is a really good answer here.