# After Adding Migrate Flag, Auto-Migration after 10 Such Flags

Tags: feature-request, migration, flags

There have been many posts about having a flag for migration, but I think that if we were to have such a flagging option, we should also **allow users to specify what site they believe the post should be migrated to**.

Next, we can **tally votes** for each site for a specific post, and if, say, **there are 10** (would 5 be better?) **flags for migrating** a post from Meta to Super User, then it would **auto-migrate**.

Comment: In other words, you want to lower the bar?

Comment: Aaaah, my eyes! All that **boooooooollllllldddd!**

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate too

Comment: Plus there is be no limit on flagging for migrating to other sites. Right now one can only flag 10 times in a day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a few extras to what ~quack said; currently (with vote -> migrate voting)

- the magic number is (IIRC) 5 close votes (of any kind)
- the *consensus* site of any "migrate" votes is chosen as the target; if there is no consensus, it is simply closed without migrate
- you can't migrate *from* meta

Or in examples:

- get 1 x "not programming related", 3 x "move to superuser", 1 x "move to serverfault"; it migrates to superuser
- get 3 x "not programming related", 1 x "move to superuser", 1 x "move to serverfault"; it gets closed without migrating

Comment: didn't know that about meta, figured that about consensus, wasn't sure about non-consensus. thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I don't think that there should be a "not programming related" just a "migrate to"

Answer (score 3):

This is basically how migration already works, except you're asking for it to be available under "flag-the-post" instead of "vote-to-close".

If you feel it needs migrating, but don't have the rep to vote-to-close, you're welcome to flag the post for moderator attention and state you believe it should be migrated.

Comment: I suspect that this creates more comments for the moderator's than needed. for example 10 differently worded moderator attentions probably are all seen by the moderator. where as 10 flag migrate to could just be shown as a single message with a count.

Comment: @xenoterracide: not really.  i can't speak to Stack Overflow, but on Super User we get a few flags requesting migration ("a few" in total, usually no more than one per question).  these are normally by users with under 3k rep, so they can't vote-to-migrate anyway.