# Migrate to WebApps when Closing a Question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Shouldn't we have an option to migrate a question to webapps SE?

Comment: If you want WebApps added to the migration paths you will have to provide a number of example questions that should have been migrated.

Answer (score 1):

This is being discussed in more broader sense at

[After Adding Migrate Flag, Auto-Migration after 10 Such Flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31000/after-adding-migrate-flag-auto-migration-after-10-such-flags)

Comment: And denied for some reason.