# Can I comment on a closed question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Twice now I've had a question closed but haven't been able follow up on why it was closed or to get clarification. Is it possible to comment on a closed question?

Comment: You can always try and flag it for moderator attention

Comment: Are you talking about this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445504/what-makes-a-macbook-pro-a-great-development-machine-closed)?  It was migrated.

Comment: And this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/171501/how-would-you-categorize-the-landscape-of-current-and-future-software-application) wasn't really a question.

Comment: @Zoredache: it was not migrated but closed as "belongs on SU" - is this new?

Comment: @Tobias, I believe it was probably closed to be migrated, and then closed/deleted for being a poor question.

Comment: @Zoredache: found it: [Why wasn’t this question, closed as “Belongs on SuperUser”, migrated to SU?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9857/why-wasnt-this-question-closed-as-belongs-on-superuser-migrated-to-su) -> Because automatic migration only happens when all close votes were "belongs on SU"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the same rules as open questions apply.

You can comment if you are the OP or if you have 50 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *clarify* your question, you should *edit* it and **emphasize** that it's an `**edit**`. Then you can flag a mod for attention if you think your modification annihilates the closing reason.